# Netplan apply warns "gateway4 has been deprecated but .yaml has no gateway4 line

Tags: netplan

I've seen a couple of other posts about the 'gateway4 has been deprecated' warning that some get when entering `sudo netplan apply`. My problem is slightly different: I get that warning even though there is no 'gateway4' line in my .yaml config file.

Running Ubuntu 22.04.1 on a headless server.

Here's the .yaml file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      addresses:
        - [ipv4 address]/32
        - [ipv6 address]/64
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: [gateway ipv4 address here]
          metric: 100
          on-link: true
        - to: ::/0
          via: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 2606:4700:4700::1111
          - 1.0.0.1
          - 2606:4700:4700::1001
```

Why might I be getting warnings about gateway4 having been deprecated?

Comment: Brute-force method? Does `grep -r gateway4 /etc` (as root) output anything?

Comment: No that returns no result.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**:

While interacting with **netplan** one's CLI output may complain about: deprecated 'gateway4' statements, routing conflicts, or even messages urging one to configure 'routing-policy'.  Messages such as:

```
** (generate:13032): WARNING **: 14:00:00.100: 'gateway4' has been deprecated, use default routes instead. See the 'Default routes' section of the documentation for more details.
```

.

```
** (process:4389): WARNING **: 14:00:00.200: gateway4 has been deprecated, use default routes instead. **
```

.

```
 ** (process:13030): WARNING **: 14:00:00.300: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency. Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.


Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in eno1 but also in eno1
```

**Fix**: Get netplan working as expected in **two** steps.

**Firstly**, traverse to `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` (or similar) and, if not already changed, change the syntax for the 'addresses' field from the two-lined format to single line format- as shown below:

Addresses field; **two-lined** format

```
[...]
addresses: 
- i.p.v.4/24
[...]
```

Addresses field; **single-line** format - change to this

```
[...]
addresses: [ "i.p.v.4/24" ]
[...]
```

**Previous** `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` Two-lined 'addresses' field

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
       - i.p.v.4/24
      nameservers:
       search: [sub.domain.tld, domain.tld]
       addresses: [d.n.s.a, d.n.s.b, d.n.s.c]
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: i.p.v.4
         on-link: true
```

**Updated** `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` Single-line 'addresses' field

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses: [ "i.p.v.4/24" ]
      nameservers:
       search: [sub.domain.tld, domain.tld]
       addresses: [d.n.s.a, d.n.s.b, d.n.s.c]
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: i.p.v.4
         on-link: true
```

**Next**, traverse to `/run/netplan/eno1.yaml` (or similar) where one must also change the format of the 'addresses' field from two-lined to single-line as explained above.  Additionally, one may find an instance of **'gateway4'** at this location. Make sure to delete or comment this out.

**Previous** `/run/netplan/eno1.yaml` Two-lined 'addresses' field + gateway4

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses: 
        - i.p.v.4/24
      gateway4: "i.p.v.4"
```

**Updated** `/run/netplan/eno1.yaml` Single-line 'addresses' field + no gateway4

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses: [ "i.p.v.4/24" ]
```

Now issue: **sudo netplan apply** and there should be no errors.

Operation can be confirmed by viewing the running configuration at: `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eno1.network` (or simliar).

```
[Match]
Name=eno1

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=i.p.v.4/24
DNS=d.n.s.a
DNS=d.n.s.b
DNS=d.n.s.c
Domains=sub.domain.tld domain.tld

[Route]
Destination=0.0.0.0/0
Gateway=i.p.v.4
GatewayOnLink=true
```

Comment: Sorry for the very late response but that was excellent and solved my problem, which was driving me crazy.

Comment: Your delayed reply is actually fortuitous and beneficial for me as I just installed some fresh hardwares and am again seeing this error-  it’s nice to have the instructions appear out of thin air!

Time to update my install script.